# ImageSize bug in Rasterize

Tags: bugs, rendering, rasterize

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 11.3.0**

---

In version 11.0.0 I am getting incorrect sizes from `Rasterize`.
The problem remains in 11.0.1

```
Rasterize["hi", "Image", ImageSize -> {100, 100}] // ImageDimensions
(* {100, 102} *)

Rasterize["hi", "Graphics", ImageSize -> {100, 100}] // First // First // Dimensions
(* {102, 100, 3} *)

Rasterize["hi", "RasterSize", ImageSize -> {100, 100}]
(* {96, 102} *)
```

Can anyone confirm this?

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I tested on MMA 11, Ubuntu 15.10 64 bits, it returns `{100,100}`, `{100,100,3}` **but** `{94, 89}`.

Comment: Win 7 V11 : `{100, 101}, {101, 100, 3}, {94, 101}`. V10.4 `{100, 100}, {100, 100, 3}, {98, 86}`

Comment: I'd report this to Wolfram http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Technical

Comment: Reported to Wolfram, case number 3685431

Comment: OSX (10.9.5) : with **"hi"** : v11.0.1 `{100,100}`, `{100,100,3}` but  **`{92,97}`**, for v10.3.1 `{100,100}`, `{100,100,3}` but  **`{98,92}`**. I also tested **"hii"** :  v11.0.1 **`{102,100}`**, **`{100,102,3}`** and  **`{102,72}`**, for v10.3.1 **`{102,100}`**, **`{100,102,3}`** AND  **`{102,58}`** !!

Comment: Hasn't it always been like this? I don't think it's new in 11.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I only noticed it in 11 because some previously working code became broken. Alexey Popkov added the edit "introduced in 8" so I assume it goes back at least that far.

Comment: The FE has many undesirable behaviours ("bugs") related to pixel rounding. It's also slow. I really wish they just rewrote the whole thing from scratch ...

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) the correct option to set the coarseness of the rasterization is `RasterSize`, whereas `ImageSize` only controls the size at which the image is displayed.

I'm not sure why I was using `ImageSize` previously, possibly `RasterSize` did not behave as advertised in an earlier version, or perhaps I didn't read the documentation carefully enough.

Anyway, in 12.2 everything appears to work as expected:

```
image = Rasterize["hi", "Image", 
   RasterSize -> {100, 100}, ImageSize -> {50, 50}];

(* displayed size *)
ImageSize /. Options[image]
(* {50, 50} *)

(* actual number of pixels in ImageData *)
ImageDimensions[image]
(* {100, 100} *)
```

Comment: I wonder if there's anyone who can check versions 12 and 12.1 to see if this got fixed in those versions...

Comment: I get the correct behavior in version 12.1.1